# Extract string embedded in pattern with a regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep, pattern-matching

I've been using the `bash` command line with `grep -e` and `sort -nr` trying to filter and analyze some lines coming from a bunch of "data" files. So far I came out with an output file like this:

```
 25 The X value is: bla bla bla done
 19 The X value is: foo done
 19 The X value is: bar done
 19 The X value is: bbb done
 19 The X value is: xxx yyy zzz done
```

where you can see the frequency and the "data" part I am interested into.

I am not able to find a regex to be used by `grep` to "clean those lines". I mean: I can intercept those "data" lines with a regex like `is:.*done` (I know this pattern is unique in the files I am analyzing), but **how can I clean those lines extracting exactly the stuff between "is:" and "done"?**

Comment: grep won't do that for you. Look at cut, which removes columns by position or delimiter, or sed, which removes regexs.

Comment: Do you need frequency and part between `is: ` and `done` both in output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sed` instead:

```
$ sed -r 's/^.*: (.*) done$/\1/' outputfile.txt

bla bla bla
foo
bar
bbb
xxx yyy zzz
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to return:

```
bla bla bla
foo
bar
bbb
xxx yyy zzz
```

you can use

```
(?<=:)(.*)(?=done)
```